# clarification on $_Files php command

Tags: php

Could someone explain to me what this php command `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` means? I saw this command and looked up the documentation and the explanation is vague and I have search on Google, but could not get a better explanation. And the "`file`" and "`error`" could it be different variable names or it has to be "file" and "error".

Comment: What do you know about php arrays in general?

Comment: @sectus just started on php and reading on arrays but having trouble understanding it. I read 'file' is the actual name defined in the input field but i get confused when other examples use 'error' or 'size'. Whats the purpose of 'error' or 'name' or 'type'

Answer (score 2):

Which part of this excellent [**PHP.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) tutorial is *vague*?

**$_FILES**

> An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method.
>
> The global $_FILES will contain all the uploaded file information. Its
>   contents from the example form is as follows. Note that this assumes
>   the use of the file upload name userfile, as used in the example
>   script above. This can be any name.
>
> $_FILES['userfile']['name'] The original name of the file on the
>   client machine.
>
> $_FILES['userfile']['type'] The mime type of the file, if the browser
>   provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime
>   type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take
>   its value for granted.
>
> $_FILES['userfile']['size'] The size, in bytes, of the uploaded file.
>
> $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] The temporary filename of the file in
>   which the uploaded file was stored on the server.
>
> $_FILES['userfile']['error'] The error code associated with this file
>   upload.

And which of the nice examples there are vague?

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILE['file']` is a `Multidimensional Associative  Array`, that will hold hold necessary info about the file that has been uploaded via the HTTP POST method,

Note `file` it can be any name , the name you give it in input file type field.

eg `<input type='file' name='any_name'>`

so the syntax now becomes `$_FILE['any_name'] ['error']`

[**More Info**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php)

Comment: so 'userfile' can be any name but has to match the name given in an input file type field. I get confused when i see the second variables such as 'error' or 'tmp_name'. Do they have different purpose?

Comment: yep, userfile can be any name(input file type field name) , error & other keyword like tmp_name just hold the necessary values pertaining to the form. eg 'tmp_name' will hold the temporary storage place name